# LittleEndian Signed value read from a binary file in java is showing as 63 instead of 157

Tags: java, binaryfiles, endianness

decodedValue below is priting 63 instead of 157.More than 500 values read from binary file are correct only for this value the problem persist

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;    
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

byte[] dataBlockBytes;    
decodedSOR = readFileAsString("binary filepath");

int index = 0;    
dataBlockBytes = decodedSOR.substring(index,index+14).getBytes();

int decodedValue= ByteBuffer.wrap(dataBlockBytes,2,4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt()
```

---

```
/**
 * To read File and return as String
 * @param filePath
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(filePath));
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    int numRead=0;
    while((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1){
        String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
        fileData.append(readData);
    }
    reader.close();
    //System.out.println("fileData.toString()===> "+fileData.toString());
    return fileData.toString();    
    }
```

Comment: Why are you reading a binary file into a string?

Comment: Don't use FileReader to read bytes. Read the Javadoc, especially about default character encoding. It's not designed for reading bytes.

Comment: Use an `InputStream` to read binary data.

Comment: Used InputStream , but still getting the value as 63 instead of 157

Comment: Are you still converting bytes to characters somewhere?

Comment: except the above code not doing any thing different.

Comment: the array is printing all the values correct except at the 2nd position.                                                                                                        
 
 
for(int n=0;n<14;n++){ System.out.println(i+" dataBlockBytes["+n+"]"+ (dataBlockBytes[n] & 0xFF )); }

Comment: Tried with commons io  EndianUtils.readSwappedInteger,readSwappedUnsignedInteger. but no change in result.

Comment: So you are *still* using `char[] buf`?

Comment: yes char[] is still being used, I am using jdk6

Comment: I used apache commons io with below two lines, still the problem persist                                                                                                     File file = new File(filePath);
FileUtils.readFileToString(file)

Comment: String s= new String( FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));  of Apache Commons io is also not working.

Comment: Used Google commons api (Guva )   ,still issue persist                         byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(in);
String s =new String(bytes)

Comment: The problem is that when you are using these utilities to convert from bytes to char, (as in `new String(byteArray)` or when using the `read()` method), you are decoding bytes to Unicode characters. This decoding assumes the data is text. It won't play nicely with binary data. If you get a byte larger than 127, and your default encoding is UTF-8, that won't do what you want it to do. Keep to bytes and don't use char or String.

Comment: @Robby String is needed to further process the binary file to get a specific index based the specific part of the string content.

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou, String is needed in my requirement to further process the binary file to get a specific index  (and content from that index ) based on the specific part of the string content.

Comment: You can still index into a byte array instead of a String. I don't quite understand why you need a String. It's not designed to hold binary data.

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou , because these are around 53kb files and lot of values are arranged based on a specific format under different labels. Based on availability of labels I have to read the data if label is available.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou,Robby Cornelissen  ,Henry                                                                                    Thank you so much , I am able to process through byte array.